# "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". How can I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I tried to run this profanity checker but I am getting a "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". How can I fix this?

Here is the code;

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def read_text():
    quotes = open("C:\Check Profanity\movie_quotes.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    encoded_text = urllib.parse.quote(text_to_check, 'utf-8')
    address = "http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+encoded_text
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(address)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()
    if "true" in output:
        print("Profanity Alert!")
    elif "false" in output:
        print("This document has no curse words!")
    else:
        print("Could not scan the document properly.")

read_text()
```

And here is the error that is being thrown out when I try to run the program.

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\check_profanity.py 
Houston, we have a problem
(Apollo 13)

Mama always said, life is like a box of chocolates.
You never know what you are going to get.
(Forrest Gump)

You can't handle the truth.
(A Few Good Men)

I beleieve everything and I believe nothing.
(A Shit in the Dark)
b'true'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\check_profanity.py", line 25, in <module>
    read_text()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\check_profanity.py", line 9, in read_text
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\check_profanity.py", line 18, in check_profanity
    if "true" in output:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `connection.read()` returns bytes, just decode it using the enconding, most likely `utf-8`

For instance to do the following:

```
connection.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Please mark the question as correct if it's the case!